# Исключения и ошибки в php. Что когда использовать и как?

Tags: php, ооп

Хочу разобраться как делать правильно.

Сейчас у меня в коде обработчик ошибок (ErrorHandler) обрабатывает как внутренние ошибки скрипта, так и исключения, которые я сам создаю. Выглядит этот так:

```
    class ErrorHandler
    { 
        public static function register()
        {
            ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            set_error_handler(get_class() . "::showError");
            register_shutdown_function(get_class() . "::catch_fatal_error");
            ob_start();
        }

        /**
         * @param int $errno
         * @param string $errstr
         * @param string $file
         * @param int $line
         * @param string $header
         */
        public static function showError($errno, $errstr, $file, $line, $header = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")
        {/*здесь отправляю ответ об ошибке*/}

        public static function catch_fatal_error()
        {
            /*здесь отправляю ответ о критической ошибке 
            при помощи все того же метода self::showError*/
        }
    }
```

Весь код приложения заключен в блок try{} и исключение обрабатывается при помощи все того же метода:

```
try{
//Здесь весь код моего приложения
//в нем встречаются такие выбросы ошибок:
throw new \Exception("Сообщение об ошибке.");
}
catch(\Exception $e){
//обрабатывается исключение при помощи все того же метода класса ErrorHandler
ErrorHandler::showError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли так делать?
2. Какой наиболее приемлемый вариант работы с ошибками и исключениями, если мой неверный?

Вопрос возник потому, что мой знакомый, которого я считаю более продвинутым чем я, говорит, что так как у меня делать нельзя. Но я не могу  понять почему. Что не так?

Некоторые важные моменты, которые я понял:

1. Когда возникает фатальная ошибка, то она автоматически попадает в
   буфер вывода. Это означает, что мы можем сразу его удалять и НЕ создавать предварительно вручную функцией `ob_start();`, если, конечно, хотим обрабатывать фатальные ошибки тоже. Что не рекомендуется делать.
2. Директива `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` в моем коде лишняя, т.к. я сам решаю, что делать с ошибками и мне не нужно сообщать php, что ему делать с ними. Я уже сам решу. А остальным пусть занимаются базовые настройки сервера.
3. Отправлять ответ пользователю внутри обработчика ошибок допустимо. Т.к. другие механизмы ответа, предусмотренные приложением, могут быть недоступны как раз из-за этих ошибок. Встроенный обработчик именно это делает - он прерывает в месте ошибки ход программы и отправляет ответ пользователю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В целом ваша механика отлова ошибок верная, потому мне не очень понятна критика вашего товарища. Было бы здорово взглянуть на его решение.

Теперь по существу. Собственно, класс обработчик ошибок:

```
class ErrorHandler
{
    protected $format = '{{message}} {{class}}::{{method}} {{file}} on line {{line}}';
    /**
     * @var HandlerInterface
     */
    protected $displayHandler;

    /**
     * @var integer the size of the reserved memory. A portion of memory is pre-allocated so that
     * when an out-of-memory issue occurs, the error handler is able to handle the error with
     * the help of this reserved memory. If you set this value to be 0, no memory will be reserved.
     * Defaults to 256KB.
     */
    protected $memoryReserveSize = 262144;
    /**
     * @var string Used to reserve memory for fatal error handler.
     */
    private $_memoryReserve;

    /**
     * Register this error handler.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Catch errors
        set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

        if ($this->memoryReserveSize > 0) {
            $this->_memoryReserve = str_repeat('x', $this->memoryReserveSize);
        }
        // Start buffer
        ob_start();
        // Catch fatal errors
        register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);
    }

    /**
     * Unregisters this error handler by restoring the PHP error handlers.
     */
    public function unregister()
    {
        restore_error_handler();
    }

    /**
     * Error handler.
     *
     * @param int $code
     * @param string $msg
     * @param string $file
     * @param int $line
     * @return bool
     * @throws \ErrorException
     */
    public function handleError($code, $msg, $file, $line)
    {
        if (~error_reporting() & $code) {
            return false;
        }

        switch ($code) {
            case E_USER_WARNING:
            case E_WARNING:
                $exception = new \ErrorException("[E_WARNING] {$msg}", Log::WARNING, $code, $file, $line);
                break;
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
            case E_NOTICE:
            case E_STRICT:
                $exception = new \ErrorException("[E_NOTICE] {$msg}", Log::NOTICE, $code, $file, $line);
                break;
            case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
                $exception = new \ErrorException("[E_CATCHABLE] {$msg}", Log::ERROR, $code, $file, $line);
                break;
            default:
                $exception = new \ErrorException("[E_UNKNOWN] {$msg}", Log::CRITICAL, $code, $file, $line);
        }

        throw $exception;
    }

    /**
     * Fatal handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleShutdown()
    {
        unset($this->_memoryReserve);

        $error = error_get_last();
        if (
            isset($error['type']) &&
            ($error['type'] == E_ERROR ||
                $error['type'] == E_PARSE ||
                $error['type'] == E_COMPILE_ERROR ||
                $error['type'] == E_CORE_ERROR)
        ) {

            $type = "";
            switch ($error['type']) {
                case E_ERROR:
                    $type = '[E_ERROR]';
                    break;
                case E_PARSE:
                    $type = '[E_PARSE]';
                    break;
                case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
                    $type = '[E_COMPILE_ERROR]';
                    break;
                case E_CORE_ERROR:
                    $type = '[E_CORE_ERROR]';
                    break;
            }
            $exception = new \ErrorException("$type {$error['message']}", Log::CRITICAL, $error['type'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
            if (APP_LOG) {
                Log::log(Log::CRITICAL, $this->convertExceptionToString($exception));
            }
            $this->display($exception);
        } else {
            if (ob_get_length() !== false) {
                // Display buffer, complete work buffer
                ob_end_flush();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a display handler.
     * @param HandlerInterface $handler
     */
    public function setDisplayHandler(HandlerInterface $handler)
    {
        $this->displayHandler = $handler;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a format message log.
     * @param string $format
     */
    public function setFormat($format)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a size memory.
     * @param int $size
     */
    public function setMemoryReserve($size)
    {
        $this->memoryReserveSize = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Exception $exception
     */
    public function display(\Exception $exception)
    {
        // display Whoops
        if (APP_DEBUG === true) {
            if (!isset($this->displayHandler)) {
                $this->displayHandler = new PrettyPageHandler();
            }
            $run = new Run();
            $run->pushHandler($this->displayHandler);
            $run->handleException($exception);
            return;
        }

        die('This site is temporarily unavailable. Please, visit the page later.');
    }

    /**
     * Converts an exception into a simple string.
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception the exception being converted
     * @return string the string representation of the exception.
     */
    public function convertExceptionToString(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $trace = $exception->getTrace();
        $placeholders = [
            '{{class}}' => isset($trace[0]['class']) ? $trace[0]['class'] : '',
            '{{method}}' => isset($trace[0]['function']) ? $trace[0]['function'] : '',
            '{{message}}' => $exception->getMessage(),
            '{{file}}' => $exception->getFile(),
            '{{line}}' => $exception->getLine(),
        ];

        return strtr($this->format, $placeholders);
    }
}
```

> Класс может быть и статическим (т.е. содержать статические методы и свойства). Не имеет значения.

За отображение исключений и ошибок в красивом интерфейсе отвечает вполне известная библиотека [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops), а логирование производится с помощью [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) (здесь представлен лёгенький wrapper над ней)

Существуют различные нюансы, к примеру, для отлова фатала связанного с переполнением памяти (`Allowed memory size of...`), необходимо зарезервировать некий объём. Опытным путём был рассчитан объём в 256KB. Об этом я узнал на одной из конференции от [Александра samdark Макарова](https://github.com/samdark) (евангелист и мэйнтейнер фреймворка yii). Собственно, в обработчике фреймворка [подобный хак имеется](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/ErrorHandler.php). Если проанализировать код обработчика yii2, то можно заментить другие нюансы связанные, к примеру, с обработкой ошибок/исключений HHVM.

В единой точке входна в ваше приложение (`index.php`) указываем следующее:

```
defined('APP_DEBUG') or define('APP_DEBUG', true);
defined('APP_LOG') or define('APP_LOG', true);

$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler;
$errorHandler->register();

try {

  // ... bootstrap вашего приложения

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if (APP_LOG) {
        $msg = $errorHandler->convertExceptionToString($e);
        Log::log($e->getCode() ? : Log::CRITICAL, $msg);
    }
    $errorHandler->display($e);
}
```

В самом приложение можно ловить локальные исключения и делать с ними всё что угодно. К примеру, ловить и тут же логировать:

```
try {

    // ... некая локальная логика приложения

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::log(Log::ERROR, (new ErrorHandler())->convertExceptionToString($e));
}
```

Так или иначе, любое выбрашенное исключение будет отловлено в `index.php` и в зависимости от заданных констант (`APP_DEBUG` и `APP_LOG`) представленно в красивом интерфейсе и добавлено в лог. Естественно на продакшене стоит обязательно отключить режим дебага.

По поводу обработчиков Whoops:

Зная в каком формате (`content type`) вам необходимо отдать данные пользователю, можно выбрать подходящий обработчик.

К примеру, проверка является ли запрос ajax-запросом

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
   $errorHandler->setDisplayHandler(new JsonResponseHandler());
}
```

Дебаг-информация будет представлена в виде json-а, что удобно для просмотра через консоль браузера.

В идеале необходимо иметь HTTP прослойку (классы Response/Request) и всё это детектить на уровне роутинга или фильтров/поведений контроллера - ContentNegotiator или что-то подобное.

P.S. Посмотрите [видео холивара](http://devconf.ru/ru/news/detail/29) про оператор подавления ошибок `@` с devconf. Очень занимательно.

---

**UPDATE**

Я лично в проектах стараюсь возвращать верные http-статусы. Вам никто не мешает выдать пользовотелю специально оформленную 404-страницу с аналогичным статусом.

```
if (headers_sent()) { // проверка: не отправлены ли уже заголовоки
   return;
}
$version = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] === 'HTTP/1.0' ? '1.0' : '1.1'
$statusCode = 404;
$statusText = 'Not Found';

header("HTTP/$version $statusCode $statusText");
```

> Как я уже отмечал ранее, лучше всего использовать класс-прослойку Response над нативными функциями.

С роутингом этого добиться досточно просто:

```
$route = new Route(); 
$route->get('/items/{id:\d+}/', ['\namespace\ItemsController', 'actionOne']);
$route->post('/items/', ['\namespace\ItemsController', 'actionCreate']);
//... другие правила
$route->any('*', ['\namespace\ItemsController', 'actionNotFound']);
// т.е. если вышеприведенные правила не выполнились, то выполнится последнее правило.
```

Для ajax-запрос, достаточно в ответе указать заголовок без тела:

```
$route->any('*', function(Route $route) {
   $route->response->status404();
   return $route->response;
});
```

403 - если доступ к ресурсу (по какому-то URL-у) запрещен для неавторизованного пользователя или пользователя с иной ролью/правами, к примеру, не имеющего права администратора. Посмотрите [RBAC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9). В yii подобный механизм реализован через поведения/фильтры к экшенам контроллера.

201 - ресурс успешно создан. К примеру, можно выдавать, когда зарегистрирован пользователь, создан комментарий или пост.

204 - запрос к БД завершился успешно, но данные по какой-то причине отсутствуют. К примеру, открылся новый раздел на сайте, но статьи для него ещё не написаны.

422 я использую, если не прошла валидация данных, к примеру формы. В данном случае, через `$statusText` (см. выше), можно дать пояснение: `Validation failure`.

429 - классический rate limiter. Чаще всего применятеся для REST API. При достижении определённого лимита на количтво запросов выдавать данный статус.

302 - при редиректе. К примеру, если данные пришедшие от формы верны и запись в БД успешно произведена, то проивзодится редирект на стороннюю страницу, либо рефреш текущий страницы с данным статус.

500 - если вы могли заметить, то в `ErrorHandler` имеется `die('This site is temporarily unavailable. Please, visit the page later.');`. Вы можете вместо этой "пресной" записи выдать пользователю статичную страницу-заглушку предварительно указав http-статус 500.

```
die(file_get_contents('/path/to/stub.html'));
```

> Для реализации своего RESTful API указание верныx http-методов, статусов, заголовков (почитайте про [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)) является обязательных.

[Полный список статусов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Таким образом, в режиме дебага у вас будет выводится Whoops со стек-трейсом, а на продакшене (боевом сервере) пользователю будет показана заглушка. Логировать или нет ошибки/исключения на ваше усмотрение. К примеру, во многих фреймворках по умолчанию производлится "информационное" логирование (level `Log::INFO`), т.е. каждое соединие с БД, успешность транзакций, авторизация пользователя и т.д., что хорошенько может так забить ваш накопитель на сервере. Необходимо повышать уровень логирования ошибок до `Log::WARNING` или `Log::ERROR`, а также использоватать штатные утилиты по ротации логов. К примеру, в Linux это [logrotate](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=logrotate&category=8).

Коль я затронул тут множество тем, то позвольте прорекламировать мои open source библиотеки:

- [Rock Route](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-route) - роутинг с гибкими правилами, группировкой (разделение правил на пространства/модули для, к примеру, ajax, backend/админка и т.д., как в laravel) и поддержкой REST. Алгоритм реализации облегчённых regexp-паттернов был взят из библиотеки [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) Никиты Попова (входит в core team PHP). Имеется подробная документация.
- [Rock Response](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-response/) - форк yii2 response, который полностью отделён от фреймворка. Документации, к сожалению нет, но существует официальная [документации yii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/runtime-responses.md). Правда, тоже пока короткая.

  > Как мы знаем yii2 является монолитным фреймворком.
- [Rock Request](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-request/) - аналогичный форк, но с моей библиотекой [фильтрации данный](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-sanitize).

Все указанные библиотеки идут без лишних зависимостей - всё только самое необходимое для их работы.

Comment: А должны ли мы явно руками передавать в заголовке ответ 404? Просто в разных фрэймворках разная реакция на ненайденую страницу. Кто-то преспокойно возвращает статус 200. Мне же кажется, что 200 возвращать как-то неправильно, если страница не найдена, а то будет получаться, что поисковик ее зачем-то индексирует. Я прав? Или можно все-таки статус 200 отдавать при ненайденной странице?

Comment: @Razzwan: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за исчерпывающий ответ. Надеюсь он будет полезен сообществу.

Comment: @Razzwan: Не за что. Хотел добавить про локальный перехват исключений (те, что в глубине кода). Исключения могут быть двух видов: системного характера и пользовательские (у Ипатьев, это пункт 2.2). Я лично не сторонник писать пользовательские исключения, а потому, перехват всех исключений происходит лишь в `index.php` с выводом заглушки или стек-трейса для тестовой среды. Но существуют некоторые некритичные сервисы, к примеру, отправка почты с помощью библиотеки [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). В данной библиотеке существует свой набор исключений `phpmailerException`.

Comment: В случае ошибки соединения с почтовым сервером или иной ошибки, вполне уместно перехватить его локально в момент отправки письма, добавить в лог, а пользователю вывести некую плашку над формой, мол "отправить письмо пока не могу...". А, к примеру, для такого сервиса, как СУБД подобное поведение является критичным, потому пусть исключение "бежит" дальше вплоть до `index.php`, где его уже будет ожидать наш базовый перехватчик.

Answer (score 6):

В целом нормально, только два замечания.

1. Заключать весь код в try catch бессмысленно и вредно. Вредно потому, что try в принципе вообще никогда не должен использоваться для показа ошибки на экране - РНР это прекрасно умеет и сам. А бессмысленно потому, что и без этого оператора ошибка прекрасно поймается.
2. **Никаких безусловных `showerror` вообще в принципе быть не должно**. Пользователь не должен видеть системные ошибки вообще никогда. То есть показ ошибки на экране может произойти только в двух случаях:

   1. Единственным пользователем сайта является сам программист - то есть на сервере разработки. В этом случае ошибки можно и нужно выводить на экран. За это должна отвечать единственная директива настройки - та, которая определяет, на боевом мы сервере, или нет.
   2. Если исключение было брошено программистом, и текст ошибки специально предназначен для показа пользователю. Для этого можно создать отдельный класс исключений, и показывать сообщение об ошибке только если исключение относится к этому классу.

Во всех остальных случаях никакого вывода на экран, кроме стандартных извинений и просьбы зайти позже, быль не должно.

Вопрос про НТТР заголовки не имеет прямого отношения к обработке ошибок и исключений, но ответ на него очевиден: НТТР статус **всегда** должен отражать текущий статус сервера. Если это ошибка сервера, то статус должен быть 5хх. Если страница не найдена, то 404. Если доступ запрещен - то 403. И так далее.

Comment: А должны ли мы явно руками передавать в заголовке ответ 404? Просто в разных фрэймворках разная реакция на ненайденую страницу. Кто-то преспокойно возвращает статус 200. Мне же кажется, что 200 возвращать как-то неправильно, если страница не найдена, а то будет получаться, что поисковик ее зачем-то индексирует. Я прав? Или можно все-таки статус 200 отдавать при ненайденной странице?

Comment: Ответ, безусловно, полезен, но менее полон, чем соседний.